.NET Core dependency injection Entity Framework lazy loading not available after insert / update
We were using a separate DbContext per function like this:
using MyEntities db = new();

This was fine, however since we have swapped to dependency injection, we have found that since the DbContext persists for each request, when creating a new entity and saving it with SaveChanges(), the lazy loading relationships aren't available.
This is causing a number of runtime errors, and we have determined that we would either need to use .Include to force the load or to set the state of the entity as "detached".
However this process would require a lot of changes, I'm wondering if there is a better solution such that the lazy loading properties were always available.

Have you configured your UseLazyLoadingProxies within program.cs while initializing your DbContext instance? Hows your other configuration looks like?

Yes optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging().UseLazyLoadingProxies() This isnt the issue, the issue is if I save an entity that entity isnt available to lazy load the properties as the saved version without the lazy loading is cached in the dbcontext.

Could you please share more details so that it can be reproduce, I was trying to simulate your issue but couldn't able to because of inadequate code snippet.

Its very simple. lets say you have an Entity Called Quote and on this multiple Prodducts. If you create a new Product and SaveChanges(). then you retrieve the product ie db.Products.find(productId). This will return the entity saved rather than load it and have no lazy loading thus you cant do product.Quote. You would need to do product = db.Products.Include(i => i.Quote).FirstOrDefault(w => w.ProductId = id)

Okay thanks for your explanation and additional details.

If the product had Quotes in the previous situation that means these quotes were already cached in the content. That's not lazy loading, that's relationship fixup. But it also indicates an unhealthy context life cycle. A context is supposed to have a short lifespan, otherwise it will get bloated and perform increasingly poor.

@DaleFraser it's not simple at all without the real code. DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. You don't call SaveChanges for every Insert, every object. you call it at the very end of the business operation/request to commit all changes at once. This doesn't change if you try to call it for every entity - your Insert can easily perform 42 pending DELETEs. The way DbContext works in eg ASP.NET Core is perfectly fine - if you don't call SaveChanges at the end of the action, all changes are discarded. If you do, all changes are saved in a single transaction

If you create a new Product and SaveChanges(). then you retrieve the product that's a bug. Post your actual code.
